# How to make Primefaces editor (p:editor) to notice when user has changed the text content?

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I would like to make it so that once user edits the value content of p:editor, a save-button next to the editor would be enabled. It is disabled when there's no change on the editor value. It doesn't even need to compare the content on every keystroke to the old content, just editing ANYTHING on it would be enough in my case.

I noticed I can't put `<p:ajax event="onchange" />` on it, because p:editor doesn't allow ajax-events. How could I do this?

Comment: What about `valueChangeListener` of `<p:editor>`? I have not implemented it. just read about attribute of  `<p:editor>`.

Comment: strangely, valueChangeListener seems to do nothing at all on p:editor. The component itself seems to have onchange-attribute, however. I managed to do the thing I tried but it seems to be quite heavy and small loading action happens every time I change the value. I decided to change the implementation.